# VBA If cells start by a Letter do

Tags: excel, vba

Hello i saw similar topics but not what i want. I just want a If condition like "if cells start by R then..."
I did that

```
Sub fgrt()

 Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim lColumn As Long
    lColumn = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Dim J As Double
    Dim I As Double


For I = 0 To lColumn
    
    For J = 3 To LastRow
    If Left(Cells(J, I).Value, 1)) = "R" Then
    Cells(J, I).Value = Cells(J, 169).Value
    End If
    Next J
    

Next I

End Sub
```

The line

```
If Left(Cells(J, I).Value, 1)) = "R" Then
```

return an error

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: `For I = 0 To lColumn`: There is no row or column `0`. Change the `0` to `1`.

Comment: You have an extra `)` too i think

Comment: I prefer using `if Cells(2, I).Value Like "R*"` . Faster and more readable. Be careful with `option Compare` however.

Comment: Thanks for the advice i didnt know

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the syntax and I changed the position of the `If`. Noe it works.

```
Sub fgrt()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim lColumn As Long
    lColumn = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Dim J As Double
    Dim I As Double

    For I = 1 To lColumn
        If Left(Cells(2, I).Value, 1) = "R" Then
            For J = 3 To LastRow
                Cells(J, I).Value = Cells(J, 169).Value
            Next J
        End If
    Next I

End Sub
```